# Moving out of a mutable self reference in enum before overwriting self

Tags: rust, enums, embedded, borrow-checker

I have a finite state machine-like enum that has different states that contain different types of buffers.

In my "transition" method, I'm updating one of the enum fields, and conditionally replace `self` with a different variant, reusing old field values.

However in one specific case, where I want to move a large buffer from the old variant to the new one, the borrow checked won't let me.

What's the proper way to do this while avoiding an expensive copy of the entire buffer?

```rust
impl EnumBased {
    fn step(&mut self) {
        match self {
            EnumBased::A(..) => { /* do something */ },
            EnumBased::B {
                buffer,  // &mut Buffer
            } => { 
                buffer.do_something()
                if something {
                    // consume buffer, moving out of self
                    let inner = buffer.to_inner();  // <-- at this point, can't move out of a mutable reference
                    // overwrite now-defunct self
                    *self = EnumBased::C { inner, ... }
                }
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That depends on the type of `buffer`, which is not shown in the question. Usually, you'd `std::mem::replace()` it with a `Default::default()` or some other cheaply generated value to take ownership from a `&mut T`.

Comment: [`std::mem::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.take.html)

Comment: It's a `heapless::HistoryBuffer`, using `std::mem::take` would mean copying it and overwriting the source with a full-sized zeroed buffer, or am I missing something?

Comment: @EugenePankov, not copying it, but moving it out and removing it with the a Default, which is (hopefully, probably) cheap. Yet, it is required so that `&mut self` is in a well-defined state during the intermittent steps of moving `HistoryBuffer` out and replacing `&mut self` with something else.

Comment: @user2722968 unfortunately the default for that type isn't cheap as it's a fixed (large) size array

Comment: @EugenePankov, even its a large (for what definition of large?), it would be cheap cpu-wise. I'd give it a try: The memory allocator may allocate that "large" array by deferring to the OS, which in turn will overcommit - so nothing actually gets allocated as long as these pages don't get written to. Which they won't, because that allocation will immediately get freed, once `&mut self` is replaced and that `HistoryBuffer` is destroyed again. Otherwise, see the answer below with respect to an `Invalid`-state (I'd rather call it `Empty`).

Comment: There is no OS, it's running on an MCU. It's the construction of the Rust struct itself that's expensive already (it includes a fixed-size zeroed array).

Answer (score 1):

First, I've changed your code into something that almost compiles.

```rust
pub enum EnumBased {
    B { buffer: Vec<u8> },
    C { buffer: Vec<u8> },
}

impl EnumBased {
    pub fn step(&mut self) {
        *self = match self {
            Self::B { buffer } => {
                buffer.pop();
                Self::C { buffer } // expected `Vec<u8>`, found `&mut Vec<u8>`
            }
            _ => todo!(),
        };
    }
}
```

If a buffer can be cheaply constructed (like `Vec`), you can briefly replace it with an empty one. One way to do that is with [`std::mem::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html).

```rust
*self = match self {
    Self::B { buffer } => {
        buffer.pop();

        let buffer = std::mem::take(buffer);
        Self::C { buffer }
    }
    _ => todo!(),
};
```

If that isn't possible, you can make your enum cheaply constructible. Either use an existing cheap variant, or make a new one specifically for this purpose. Then you can use [`std::mem::replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html) to briefly replace `self`.

```rust
pub enum EnumBased {
    B { buffer: Vec<u8> },
    C { buffer: Vec<u8> },
    Invalid
}

impl EnumBased {
    pub fn step(&mut self) {
        *self = match std::mem::replace(self, Self::Invalid) {
            Self::B { mut buffer } => {
                buffer.pop();
                Self::C { buffer }
            }
            _ => todo!(),
        };
    }
}
```

The advantage of using a dedicated variant is that if you see it outside this function, you know something has gone wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately neither is viable. `heapless` structures are fixed size and cannot be constructed cheaply, and `rustc` doesn't do any clever optimizations in your second approach, meaning the entire structure is moved out and back in every time (my case is extremely performance sensitive)

Comment: I'm trying an alternative approach right now that seems to work - having the enum take a `&mut` of the buffer instead of owning it, and cheaply `core::mem::replace`ing it with an (unsafe) reference to a `static mut` temporary value - while it's unsafe as hell it's probably sound as long as there's only one instance of the enum ever existing